# How can I get the video from RPScreenRecorder or add a share button?

Tags: ios, swift, rpscreenrecorder

I'm recording video using `RPScreenRecorder.shared().startRecording`. However, I want to let the user share the video from within the app. This is the code that stops recording and previews the video in a view controller and gives the user the option to save to photos or cancel.

I cannot figure out how to grab the video from the view controllers view. When I dug into the subviews: `preview.view.subviews.first!.subviews.first!` There's a view of type: `UIRemoteView` with no subviews.

Is it possible to grab the video? Or better yet, is there a way to show a `UIActivityViewController` to allow the user to share the video?

for macOS I could do `preview.mode = .share`, but for iOS this is not available.

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopRecording { preview, error in
    guard let preview = preview else { return }
    self.present(preview, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 'mode' is unavailable in iOS. I should have made that clear.

Comment: RPPreviewViewController on iOS has share button that invokes standard UIActivityViewController.

Comment: When I add: preview.mode = .share I get the error message: 'mode' is unavailable in iOS. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You do have RPPreviewViewController on iOS, and it has the share button, nothing needs to be configured.

Comment: The mode property is only available in tvOS 10.0+. Check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rppreviewviewcontroller/1841266-mode

Comment: Not a wise way! But, you get last video saved in Photos if you have Access to Photo Library in the app. I guess if saves to Photos u already have. So maybe it is the easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a share button but it is not visible, if view controller is not presented fullscreen, I think this is a bug related to `PRPreviewViewController`.

You can change modalTransitionStyle and see share button.

```
RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopRecording { preview, error in
    guard let preview = preview else { return }
    preview.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    self.present(preview, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```